# "Bad password" error when connecting to a password protected server

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm trying to connect to a password-protected CS:GO server by using the Steam protocol using `steam://connect/ip:port/password`.

When CS:GO is already running, the client connects without any problems. But when CS:GO is not running, it starts and then gives me the "Bad password" error.

Is this a known bug? I haven't found anything so far.

Comment: How is Steam supposed to know which application to use if one isn't running?

Comment: It does that automatically. It checks which Server is running on the IP, I guess.

Comment: What if you have more than one Steam app running?  What happens then?  I'm guessing it'll do the same thing.

Comment: It tries to start CS:GO but can't because another App is already running. It definitely knows, that it's a CS:GO server I want it to connect to.

Comment: Yes, Steam checks what protocol is behind the address and this determines the game to launch. Maybe try `steam://connect/ip:port/password "yourPassword"` The client should take arguments like that.

Comment: @Frank Steam can tell which app the server is using because the appid (730 for CS:GO) is in the server's [`A2S_INFO` response](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries#A2S_INFO).

Comment: @dly That doesn't work. The protocol itself works, but the game only takes the password parameter when it's already running.

Comment: Okay, I tested some things. If I start the game with `steam://connect/ip:port/serverPassword`, the password variable in CS:GO is being set to "password serverPassword" instead of "serverPassword". So it's basically Steam's fault.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I think I found why:

How to reproduce:

1. Issue a steam url: Steam://connect/ip/password.
2. Wait for CS to start and then connect.
3. Close down CS.
4. On your server: Change the password
5. Issue a steam url: Steam://connect/ip/new_password.
6. "SteamUrlHandler" now starts CS and then issues the connect command.
7. You get BadPassword response from server.

Question Why?

I used a protocol analysator and detected that it uses the old password during the 2nd connect. So the "SteamUrlHandler" has older passwords cached and sends that to the game.

Workaround?

Still looking after a good workaround, but issuing the steam-url again after a while seems to work.

Comment: Passworded server issues are just as old as the game and most of them haven't been fixed since. At least they fixed the problem with passworded servers not checking the passwords and allowing everyone in. A good workaround would be to just store the most used password in your config with `password somePW` and join your server without entering it (`steam://connect/ip:port/`).

Comment: That's some amazing research. Thank you very much!